# failed to connect to mysql database using java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am trying to connect to MySQL database and fetch some data using sql statement in my java code. but i cant connect to my database with the following SQL Exception.

ERROR: `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

my java code is as bellow:

**Mysql_connecter.java**

```
package mysql_connecter;

import java.sql.*;
/**
 *
 * @author kass
 */
public class Mysql_connecter 
{
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("connecting.....");
            try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","user","password")) 
            {
                System.out.println("connected to mysql DB");
                Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from my_table");

                while(rs.next())
                {
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            { 
                System.out.println("ERROR: ["+e+"]");
            }
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        { 
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    } 
}
```

i have added the mysql jdbc driver to my library path. can some one point me i miss something in my code?

Comment: Please try to access to the database using  a MysqlClient like PHPMyAdmin or Heidisql. If you cannot access with a client - you cannot expect that it works with java.

Answer (score 0):

seems you have no password set for your user.
Go to `mysql` database and check `user` table to confirm the username and password for the user.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with using Username+Password combination but not having native authentication enabled on database side.

Are you able to change the password of the user using this command:

```
ALTER USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'password';
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-user.html

For more information on how native authentication works see

[MySQL 8.0 Reference for Native Pluggable Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/native-pluggable-authentication.html)

or if you are using MySQL 5.7 see [MySQL 5.7 Reference for Native Pluggable Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/native-pluggable-authentication.html)